# Meaning of "Analyze yourself"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

If I say "Analyze yourself" to someone, does it mean I am asking someone to analyze himself or asking him to analyze something by himself (without someone else's assistance?

Comment: The short answer to your question is 'Yes.' (It could mean either one, although your first option seems the more likely one.)

Comment: |Analyze yourself| means to do work on yourself. |Analyze it yourself| is used for something other than yourself.